# What is meant by red mark on review queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queue

I can see red mark on suggested edits review queue. If I click on the queue it appears to be clear and there is nothing to review. What could be the reason? Is it a known bug?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain, as I haven't seen it in writing, but from what I gather, a red dot on the `Suggested Edits` queue means there is a *tag wiki* with pending edits. This is a permission which [requires 5k rep](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), so it makes sense you wouldn't yet be able to carry out this task. As for red dot in the `Low Quality Review`, `Close Vote`, etc. I believe it indicates there are *flags* on posts sitting in the queue.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your input. Let me see if any other view on the same.

Comment: I see the same behavior as Reshma, and I do have tag wiki permissions. I have a red dot right now on "Low Quality Posts" but the queue is empty. No idea what it means.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226